# Adding a Java element that's a subclass of a list, within a method with generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have some code that does some operations on a list, but would be simplified if I could also add objects that are a subclass of the list.

Here is a greatly simplified example of what I mean.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FailListInsert {
    public static abstract class A {
        int a = 0;
        public A(final int newA) {
            a = newA;
        }
        public abstract void f();
    }
    public static class A1 extends A {
        int a1 = 0;
        public A1(final int newA) {
            this(newA, 0);
        }
        public A1(final int newA, final int newA1) {
            super(newA);
            a1 = newA1;
        }
        public void f() {
            a1++;
        }
    }
    public static class A2 extends A {
        String a2 = "";
        public A2(final int newA) {
            this(newA, "+");
        }
        public A2(final int newA, final String newA2) {
            super(newA);
            a2 = newA2;
        }
        public void f() {
            a2 = a2 + "+";
        }
    }
    enum AType {
        A1_TYPE { public A newA(final int a) {
                return new A1(a);
            } },
        A2_TYPE { public A newA(final int a) {
                return new A2(a);
            } };
        public abstract A newA(final int a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<A1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<A2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        insertA(AType.A1_TYPE, list1, 1);
        insertA(AType.A2_TYPE, list2, 2);
    }
    public static void insertA(final AType t, final List<? extends A> al, final int x)
    {
        final var newA = t.newA(x);
        al.add(newA);
    }
}
```

I understand why this can't work. if `insertAt()` were called with `A1_TYPE` and `list2` as parameters, it would end up sneaking `A1` elements into a list declared `List<A2>`.

I feel like something about this approach is fundamentally wrong for Java (it's find for e.g. Python), but exactly what the right way should be eludes me. The actual code does a lot of work on the common class list, and uses the results for the parameters for the new subclass objects. Even separating the first part into a helper method still leaves a lot of duplicate code identical except for the types of the list and added objects.

Any other strategy I can think of is messier than the existing duplicated code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

methods can have generics. Unfortunately, enums can't; not in the way we need here (we need `A1_TYPE` to have different generics than `A2_TYPE` does; that's not something enums support. It's an annoying and well known limitation).

So, you have to ditch that enum. Also, your example is deplorable; generics are by convention single letter capitals, so naming an actual type 'A' here is.. very very confusing.

I had to do a number on your example to fix it as a consequence.

We're going to replace that enum with a series of classes, and use JDK15+'s new `sealed` feature to maintain the property enums have that other code can't just start making implementations of your AType concept without your code's consent.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SuccessListInsert {
    public static abstract class Animal {
        int a;
        public Animal(int age) {
            a = age;
        }
        public abstract void f();
    }
    public static class Dog extends Animal {
        int b;
        public Dog(int age) {
            this(age, 0);
        }
        public Dog(int age, int hairLength) {
            super(age);
            b = hairLength;
        }
        public void f() {
            b++;
        }
    }
    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        String b;
        public Cat(int age) {
            this(age, "Tabby");
        }
        public Cat(int age, String breed) {
            super(age);
            b = breed;
        }
        public void f() {
            b = b + " mix";
        }
    }
    sealed interface AnimalFactory<A extends Animal> permits DogFactory, CatFactory {
      A newAnimal(int age);
    }
    
    static final class DogFactory implements AnimalFactory<Dog> {
      public static final DogFactory INSTANCE = new DogFactory();
      @Override public Dog newAnimal(int age) {
        return new Dog(age);
      }
    }
    
    static final class CatFactory implements AnimalFactory<Cat> {
      public static final CatFactory INSTANCE = new CatFactory();
      @Override public Cat newAnimal(int age) {
        return new Cat(age);
      }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
        
        insertAnimal(DogFactory.INSTANCE, dogs, 1);
        insertAnimal(CatFactory.INSTANCE, cats, 2);
    }
    
    public static <A extends Animal> A insertAnimal(AnimalFactory<A> factory, List<A> list, int age) {
      A newAnimal = factory.newAnimal(age);
      list.add(newAnimal);
      return newAnimal;
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Sealed interfaces are the most direct replacement here; it achieves mostly the same goals: You fully control all implementations and nobody can add any unless *you* do so.
- Factory is how these things are usually called in java.
- Please cut it out with the `final` tourettes. It's an anti-pattern. If you dislike your parameters being modified, tell your IDE to warn when you do that, don't make your code unreadable by adding it *everywhere*.
- Generics are entirely the domain of `javac`. They are gone, or at least completely ignored, by the runtime. Hence, it helps to think of generics are **ways to link types together**. Generics aren't useful except in how it establishes links *between* usages of the same typevar. If you declare a generics typevar, it should be used in at least 2 places or it doesn't do anything. That signature of the `insertAnimal` method states: There is a link between all the 3 As: They must all be the same type. You must hand this method both an `AnimalFactory` instance as well as a `List` instance, and, both instances need to be of the same type (e.g. both `Dog`, for example). That type is *also* the return type. All 3 types are the same. It's the caller's choice as to what that type is; this code is written so that it works regardless of the choice that the caller makes. However, this code does stipulate a restriction: The type chosen must either be `Animal`, or some subtype of `Animal`.
- For completeness' sake the full generics sigs of the two parameters are best stated as `AnimalFactory<? extends Animal>` for the factory and `List<? super Animal>` for the list. This is as per PECS rules (Producer Extends, Consumer Super): If we are mentally thinking of this method invocation as being about Dogs, well, a factory that can only make Huskys is no problem; all huskies are dogs. A list that will accept any object is similarly not a problem; all dogs are objects. Hence, `Dog dog = insertAnimal(huskyFactory, listOfObjects);` is still fine. This is rarely actually useful, so, if this goes over your head, you can make all of it just `<A>` and it's unlikely to be a problem. Think about it this way: The caller must pick a type upon invoking this method. That type must be `Animal` or some subtype of it. Then, the caller must [A] pass a Factory whose type is either the chosen type or a subtype of it (because we will ask it to make a thing and want to treat it as thing of the chosen type) [B] pass a list whose type is either the chosen type or some supertype of it (because we want to add things of the chosen type to it), and [C] gets to treat the value returned by the invocation as a thing of the chosen type.

Comment: Thank you. I used Enums as a short placeholder, I don't need something behaving identically. Basically just need to understand generics better, this will help.

Comment: @JohnBayko If understanding of generics is the primary issue, please review the last 2 bullets at the end, which I added to explain how to think about what those generics are doing. If it's useful like this, consider accepting the answer; it'll guide future folk looking for an answer.

Comment: Note that when the subclasses of a `sealed` type are within the same `.java` file, you don’t need an explicit `permits` clause. And when you limit the factories to have only those two, it might be consistent to make `Animal` a `sealed` type too. By the way, an interesting alternative to having an `abstract` base class `Animal` might be: `public sealed interface Animal { int age(); }
public record Dog(int age, int hairLength) implements Animal { public Dog(int age) { this(age, 0); }}
public record Cat(int age, String breed) implements Animal { public Cat(int age) { this(age, "Tabby"); }}`

Comment: @Holger The example had an abstract class because the real life problem has mutable state that would be more duplication than I want to have to add it to every implementing class. I think it would be an easier problem if I could have done that.

Comment: @JohnBayko yes, this doesn’t work for every scenario but I wanted to add this option for completeness. Especially, as both, `sealed` types and `record` types are rather new in Java, so this alternative is not obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If generic enums were possible in Java, then this would be a simple solution, but unfortunately that is not possible. Here is an option that may suit your needs.

Create a generic interface that contains your `newA` method:

```java
public interface AType<T extends A> {
    T newA(final int a);
}
```

Then create a class that will contain `public static` instances of this interface, somewhat simulating an enum:

```java
public static class ATypes {
    public static AType<A1> A1_TYPE = new AType<A1>() {
        @Override
        public A1 newA(int a) {
            return new A1(a);
        }
    };
    public static AType<A2> A2_TYPE = new AType<A2>() {
        @Override
        public A2 newA(int a) {
            return new A2(a);
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks to Java 8+ function references, we can simplify this class significantly:

```java
public static class ATypes {
    public static AType<A1> A1_TYPE = A1::new;
    public static AType<A2> A2_TYPE = A2::new;
}
```

Then, change the syntax of your `insertA` method to be generic with the bounds of `T extends A`:

```java
public static <T extends A> void insertA(final AType<T> t,
                                         final List<T> al,
                                         final int x) {
    final T newA = t.newA(x);
    al.add(newA);
}
```

Now the following code will work:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<A1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<A2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    insertA(ATypes.A1_TYPE, list1, 1);
    insertA(ATypes.A2_TYPE, list2, 2);

    // the following will not compile (types switched)
    // insertA(ATypes.A2_TYPE, list1, 1);
    // insertA(ATypes.A1_TYPE, list2, 2);
}
```

Alternatively, you could always skip the intermediate type and just pass the function reference directly like so:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<A1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<A2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    insertA(A1::new, list1, 1);
    insertA(A2::new, list2, 2);
}

public static <T extends A> void insertA(final Function<Integer, T> t,
                                         final List<T> al,
                                         final int x) {
    final T newA = t.apply(x);
    al.add(newA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a better idea of how to use generics properly.